# JS requestAnimationFrame frame-rate

Tags: javascript

JavaScript, requestAnimationFrame:

You know how the frame-rate is different in different situations (i.e. different browsers for eg)

How do I find out the frame-rate in a particular case?

Thank you

Comment: *"The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation."*, it's usually pretty darn accurate, but if you really want to know the framerate just count callbacks per second for a few seconds, and get the average, should be accurate enough for most things.

Comment: you've got a high precision parameter passed in your callback of `rAF()`, just save it out of the scope of the callback and check the difference with last saved on next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to find frame rate that relies on `requestAnimationFrame()` for any device that supports it. Only drawback is that precision is not instantaneous. You could easily round to the nearest standard framerate and get a very quick return value that way, but this code calculates an average over 60 frames to get a more accurate reading of `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```
function RAF_tester() {
    var i = 1;
    var prevT;
    requestAnimationFrame(function(startT) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function RAF_loop(currentT) {
            var elapsedT = currentT - startT;
            var RAF_interval = currentT - prevT;
            var RAF_average = 1000 / (elapsedT / i);
            console.log(RAF_interval);
            diagnostic.innerHTML = 'Average FPS: '+RAF_average;
            prevT = currentT;
            i += 1; if (i<61) { requestAnimationFrame(RAF_loop); }
        });
    });
}
```

Hopefully it works for you!

Try it on codepen: http://codepen.io/kandleflame/pen/QEgQoE

Comment: ... create a new `Date` Object and relate on his inaccurate `now()` method while there is a high precision time parameter passed in the callback of the rAF... that's odd...

Comment: You don't even need to call `performance.now()`, it's already passed as an argument in your callback : in `requestAnimationFrame(function(time){})` `time` will be a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) just as the one returned by `performance.now()`. No need to call anything and it will represent the time when the full stack of requested functions have been called, while calling it yourself will only return the time of when you called it It will differ when other functions were stacked before, and also just because the call takes some time

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Updated the code following your advice, thanks!